# Error: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building an admin suite for an E-commerce website.

However when the same product ID is used, the following message is displayed:

> Error: Duplicate entry '14777' for key 'PRIMARY'

Is there a way to edit this message to something like "This ID is already in use, please try another ID?

Thanks in advcnce

Comment: This sounds like a MySQL error message. Which e-commerce system is that?

Comment: Should probably change that key to auto-increment and not bother the user with "giving" you a unique key.

Comment: You cant edit this message, Its the syntax error message of mysql, by the way why you want to change the message??

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752745/create-custom-error-message-mysql   OP, try searching for your answer a little before wasting peoples' time. If you can't work that out, you have no business building any sort of app

Comment: You should never let users see the error messages of your backend systems. Capture the errors and act accordingly (This may be an error page, but doesn't have to be)!

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbale_name WHERE ID='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($numRows>0) {
   echo "This ID is already in use, please try another ID?";
} else {
   //Insert query here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however i now get `This ID is already in use, please try another ID
Error: Duplicate entry '11161' for key 'PRIMARY'`?